# Will a fan cause pendant lights to move?

Tags: electrical

I know this may be a silly question, but didn't know if anyone else has run into this.  I have an 11 x 11 kitchen and existing fan and some track lighting.  I want to use track pendant lights and was wondering how bad they would move around if I had the fan on to.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a ceiling fan, probably not at all. Ceiling fans push air down or up. If you had a fan mounted on the wall pushing against the side of the lamps, you would probably get movement. But not with a ceiling fan.